# What is the pseudocode for the fastest possible k-nearest-neighbors (KNN) algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

I have a BERT model that's fine-tuned so that given a sentence in my X column, the model gives a vector that approximates the corresponding sentence in my multidimensional Y array.

I'd like to use the model-generated outputs as inputs to a KNN model that predicts which of the sentences in Y best corresponds to the generated input. This is to predict which row in Y best corresponds to a given sentence in Y.

SKLearn's KNN algorithm seems to be rather slow, so I'm wondering what the fastest KNN algorithm I can implement is.

Comment: What is your question??

Comment: @whuber I want to know how to pick the k nearest neighbors as quickly as possible.

Comment: There are entire books just on specialized aspects of the problem, depending on the numbers of points, the dimensions, storage and computing constraints, and so on.  This problem is fundamental to the field of *computational geometry,* because it is tantamount to finding a generalized Voronoi diagram.  Implementing good algorithms is not trivial and, unless you are a researcher in this field, almost surely not worth your time and effort. Consider, then, looking for software suitable to your specific problem and use case(s).

Comment: @whuber thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is special approximate nearest neighbor algorithms. Have a look at the tree-based annoy from spotify or the hash-based faiss from facebook.

---

Maybe I do not fully understand your question, but why don't you compute the scalar product of your embeddings and then sort (like in semantic search applications) to find the closest embeeding? It is also reasonably fast.